# I'm trying to get all rows in a DataGridView that have a specific column in common.

Tags: c#, select, datagridview

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string sid;
    try
    {
        txtOut.Clear();
        sid = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["ServerType"].Value.ToString();
        txtOut.Text = sid;
        txtOut.Refresh();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }

    List<string> lst2 = new List<string> ();
    DataGridView dgv1 = new DataGridView();

    //load dgv1 with the rows
    foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        dgv1.Rows.Add(r);

        string scolumn = r.DataGridView.Columns.Equals(3).ToString();
        txtOut.Text = r.ToString();
        txtOut.Refresh();
    }

    string[] q1 = lst2.Distinct().ToArray();
    listBox1.DataSource = q1;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and write what you want. And what do you mean by specific column? Are you saying that all those rows who have same text for a particular column?

Comment: I'm with @Faisal Hafeez, I don't understand the question or the intent of the code. Please ask a specific question. Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Several of the rows will have the same values in selected columns. I am trying click on the cell in the column then: 1.) use that value to get all the rows that have that same value. 2.) The pull the data from a different column from the rows that match the value in the first point (1.). 3.) Then move that data into a list box on the windows form. If the logic is wrong, Please assist. I've not done any coding like this in over 10 years, so I'm a bit rusty.. Thanks in advance for your insight and assistance.incorrect.

Comment: BTW, I tried this with a DataTable and hit the same wall. I know all the data is there, as I can see it in the windows form.  So either my logic is bad, Or the way I'm going about the code is